# Why can't I load js and css when using hexo publish blog

Tags: css, node.js, blogs, github-pages, hexo

I want to use hexo to public my blog on github.I can get my webpage using localhost:4000 but after deployed to github.I can only get page with words but js and css can't be loaded. 
here is the error message from chrome console

---

http://rudy-zhang.github.io/css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

---

There is no content in css file but I can find content in the files of repository.

When I install hexo I get warning

```
> $ npm install hexo -g
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.5
|
> dtrace-provider@0.4.0 install C:\Users\Rudy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\h
exo\node_modules\bunyan\node_modules\dtrace-provider
> node scripts/install.js npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.0
```

I'm not familiar with nodejs so I don't know if it's the place something wrong.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `hexo2.8` is a good choose.
I had the same problem,cause I changed the themes's css style.And then I back to hexo2.8,the problem missing.

`npm install hexo@2.8 -g`

Comment: I found the solustion. Check this [issue on github](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1121) if you are interested in.

Comment: @RudyZhang I'm facing the same issue and your link is not in english. Can you tell me how to solve this problem?